# Mongoose find by field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoDb and mongoose with nodejs (express) and everything works fine, except for this function:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    promotions.find({active:"true"},function(err,promo){
        if (err)  throw err;

        res.render('index',
            {
                promos: promo
            });

    });

});
```

It brings back an empty array in promo, but I do have documents in my db.

The problem seems to be with the field active in "{active:"true"}". When I look for documents without any filter (with "find({},...") it works fine.

When I run db.promotions.find({active: "true"}) in mongo it works.

This is my promotion schema:

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var promotionSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    url: String,
    image: String,
    active:
        {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
});

var Promotion = mongoose.model('Promotion', promotionSchema, 'promotions');

// make this available to our Node applications
module.exports = Promotion;
```

This is what I get in mongodb:

[image]

I've tried every possible formats of {active:true} ({"active":"true"}, {"active":true}, etc..) and nothing works.

Comment: I think db.Promotions.find() will just return empty! Check it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data types of the fields as defined in your schema have to match the data types of the fields in the document.

So because `active` is a string in your documents, you need to define it as string in your schema as well:

```
var promotionSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    url: String,
    image: String,
    active:
        {
            type: String,
            default: 'false'
        }
});
```

Otherwise, with `active` defined as a `Boolean` in your schema, Mongoose will cast any `active` value in your query to either `true` or `false`, which won't match the `'true'` and `'false'` string values in your docs.

Of course, if `active` actually *should* be a boolean in your docs, then you need to update all your docs so that they match your existing schema. This would be preferable to using string values for booleans.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem. I changed my documents to Boolean in mongoDB because that's what they should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for subscriptions to load, especially at the root (default) route. Try moving the find to a helper in the `index` template and wrap it (or the layout) in the reactive `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` block

See also:

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/